# How do I use an optional boolean property as a hint to require another property?

Tags: jsonschema

Imagine a JSON document with only two possible properties:

1. `persist`: a boolean flag. defaults to `true`
2. `dbName`: a string.

When `persist` is `true`, the `dbName` property *must* be present in the document. When `persist` is `false`, the `dbName` property *must* *not* be present in the document.

Seems simple enough--here's the schema I've come up with:

```js
{
    "description": "Example",
    "$id": "https://example.com/example",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "persist": {
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "dbName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "$comment": "persist attr is present and == false, dbName should not be present",
            "properties": {
                "persist": {
                    "enum": [
                        false
                    ]
                }
            },
            "not": {
                "required": [
                    "dbName"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "$comment": "persist attr is present and == true, require dbName",
            "properties": {
                "persist": {
                    "enum": [
                        true
                    ]
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "dbName"
            ]
        },
        {
            "$comment": "persist attr is missing, its default value is true, require dbName",
            "properties": {
                "persist": false
            },
            "required": [
                "dbName"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It *almost* works. Three test documents to exercise the three possible cases:

`{ "persist": true, "dbName": "dn" }` --> Valid

`{ "persist": false }` --> Valid

`{ "dbName": "dn" }` --> Invalid with the errors below:

```js
[{
        keyword: 'not',
        dataPath: '',
        schemaPath: '#/oneOf/0/not',
        params: {},
        message: 'should NOT be valid'
    },
    {
        keyword: 'oneOf',
        dataPath: '',
        schemaPath: '#/oneOf',
        params: {
            passingSchemas: [Array]
        },
        message: 'should match exactly one schema in oneOf'
    }
]
```

Through trial and error, it's clear that this last document is actually matching two of the conditions in the `oneOf`: `oneOf/1` and `oneOf/2`.

I have no idea why it would match `oneOf/1` since the `persist` property is absent from the json document. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comments for your `oneOf` subschemas, you have said you expect the schema to validate that the `persist` attribute is present, but it does not.

Let's take a look at why this is the case...

> Validation succeeds if, for each name that appears in both the
> instance and as a name within this keyword's value, the child
> instance for that name successfully validates against the
> corresponding schema.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.5.4

This means that, the value subschemas are applied to the instance values in the object IF the corrosponding key exists. If it does not, then it's not applied.

As such, if you discount `properties` from `oneOf/1` and `oneOf/2`, they are equivilent subschemas.

What you want for `oneOf/2` is...

```
{
  "$comment": "persist attr is present and == true, require dbName",
  "properties": {
    "persist": {
      "const": true
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "persist",
    "dbName"
  ]
}
```

Here's a demo: https://jsonschema.dev/s/cqMDM

You'll want to make the same change to `oneOf/0` too.

If you don't specify `persist` as required, the subschema will not be checking if the key exists or not.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and correct response. The resulting schema correctly validates my test documents with your fix. I've put it here for future reference:
https://jsonschema.dev/s/qNwil

Comment: You're welcome. Good idea! - For any questions which don't fit on StackOverflow, feel free to join the JSON Schema slack server. If you'd like to buy me a coffee to say thanks further, you'll find a link on my profile =]